# Problem displaying custom favicon

Tags: theme, frontend, custom-theme, developer-mode

I am encountering an issue when theming on Magento CLI 2.3.5-p1.
I want to customize the favicon.

During my first attempt I just drop a new icon on web folder and named it favicon.ico.
It works but only when I am on the customer login page (my theme inherits from blank). So that's the first issue : I want my icon to show on every pages.

Then I tried doing it with an image with custom name. It didn't worked at all. I don't know what to do I have followed EVERY tutorials.

Here is my theme arborescence :

```
|Violette
|-themeviolette
|---Magento_Theme
|-----layout
|-------default_head_blocks.xml
|-----web
|------favicon.ico
|---media
|---registration.php
|---theme.xml
```

My default_head_blocks.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Theme::vio.ico" rel="icon" sizes="16x16" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Thank you very much for saving me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the line endings of my files from CTRL to LF (I am working on a remote server from Windows)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing looks correct

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/favicon.html

What if you try via admin config? Same results?

If you switch browser do you see icon on other pages?

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I actually see my icon on every pages except home. I just tried it with another browser and same results. I didn't try it via admin because I want to practice theming by my own and I feel like using the admin panel is a little bit like cheating...